# RxSwift var-outlet binding organistaion

Tags: ios, swift, binding, rx-swift

I'm try to use RxSwift in my code and have a question:

- I have a `Settings` class with different properties (`staticValue` for example):

  ```
  class DeviceSettings: NSObject {    
      var staticValue = Variable<Int>(0)
  }
  ```
- I have an UI with UITextField which should be two-way connected with property, which works fine:

  ```
  settings.staticValue.asObservable()
      .map({ String($0) })
      .bindTo(staticValueField.rx.text)
      .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

  staticValueField.rx.controlEvent([.editingDidEnd]).asObservable()
      .map({ Int(self.staticValueField.text!)! }) // Always Int
      .subscribe(onNext: {
          self.settings.staticValue.value = $0
      }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
  ```

But actual `Settings` object will be loaded via network request and can be reloaded several times during VC lifecycle. 
So:

1. How I should store my settings object? As usual variable or as
   `Variable<Settings>` with `?` or `!`?
2. Is my two-way-binding correct?
3. In which order I need to load data and call bind logic to enable binding and set start value at once?

Answer (score 0):

1. Storing as usual variable. All observable properties is inside and stored as `Variable<T>`
2. It seems binding is correct and all works fine for now
3. - I performed network request
   - Stored received object in my Setting object variable. If I will need to refresh data, I will update object properties values, but NOT the full object
   - Added `.startWith( settings.staticValue.value )` to value -> tf binding for initial value

P.S. Correct me, if I made some mistake